# Wordpress meta_query not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to all records from my postmeta table where meta_key = 'teljesitmeny' and meta_value between 0 and 150.
I make this query, but it's not working:

```
$argsg = array( 
    'post_type'   => 'termek',
    'meta_query' => array(

            array(
            'key' => 'teljesitmeny',
            'value' => array(0, 150),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            ),              
        ),
    );
$scheduled = '';
$scheduled = new WP_Query( $argsg );
```

It's only post one query, where meta_value is 150.

Datas in postmeta table:

[image]

Datas after execute the query:

[image]

What did i wrong?

**Update:**

I found the solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `eopwrqjnc_postmeta` 
WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  'teljesitmeny'
AND  `meta_value` 
BETWEEN CAST( 0 AS UNSIGNED ) 
AND CAST( 150 AS UNSIGNED ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```